# console exe (made in C#) runs from cmd prompt but not from a batch file on Windows 7

Tags: c#, windows, windows-7, batch-file

I remember I used to write in a .bat

```
call myprog.exe
```

But dos says call not a command ?!!

My question is not about cmd prompt but BATCH file.

I tried also

```
c:\some-path\myprog.exe
```

and

```
"c:\some-path\myprog.exe"
```

the error message: the exe is not a recognized internal command. It is a console application made in C# which runs if I launch it directly in cmd prompt not in batch

Update: the 2 first character ouput is weird there are some weird 2 chars I think it happens since I installed msysgit client http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/ which has somehow made something to command prompt.

Hope I can uninstall it...

I uninstalled it but still got the weird chars in front of my command:

```
'´++"C:\some-path\prog-example.exe"' is not recognized ...
```

Comment: look at start http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154075/using-the-dos-start-command-with-parameters-passed-to-the-started-program

Comment: Just use myprog.exe or c:\path\to\myprog.exe

Comment: I don't want to launch in cmd prompt, I want in a batch file.

Comment: @PeeHaa doesn't work in a BATCH file. Only works in cmd prompt that way.

Comment: It is basically the same. Try it! Or I misunderstood teh question but if you do c:\windows\notepad.exe it runs notepad

Comment: I already tried it doesn't work that's why I ask.

Comment: @user something else is going wrong. What's the output of the command?

Comment: Hmm you're right the ouput is weird there are some weird 2 chars I think it happens since I installed msysgit client http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have include full path for the exe file. Also if any of your directories in the path has spaces, don't forget to include the whole text in quotes.

Example:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Winamp\winamp.exe
```

Note: If you create a batch file and does not work as you expected. Run the batch file from command prompt and it will display the error message.

Comment: I tried the error message: the exe is not a recognized internal command. It is a console application made in C# which runs if I launch it directly in cmd prompt not in batch

Comment: like I said.. Did you include the full path?

Comment: Does your program depend on any other DLLs, etc. that are in the same working directory?  A batch file by default isn't going to move your working directory to the location of the program.

Comment: ok I think mysgit client has done something to my command prompt so it doesn't work any more.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
myprog
```

No need for the full path as long as it's on the PATH.

Answer (score 1):

"call" is only used for running another batch file.

As shoban says, just use the name of the .exe

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in [start](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770297(WS.10).aspx) command.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using 
cmd /c X:\path_to\myprog.exe