# How to run a background process by PHP in windows?

Tags: php, windows, exec, background-process, environment

I try to run a Python script as a background process from PHP on Windows using `exec()` on this way:

```
<?PHP
    $python    = 'C:\\Users\\User\\anaconda3\\python.exe';
    $py_script = 'C:\\wamp\\www\\lab\\ex\\simple_test.py';
    $py_stdout    = '> temp\\'.session_id()."_std.txt";
    $py_stderror  = '2> temp\\'.session_id()."_stde.txt";

    exec("$py_bg $python $py_script $py_stdout $py_stderror &");
```

The script called and worked correctly, but PHP still waiting for the script.
I removed the end `&` as I foundout it's only work on Linux and after searching other Q&A find this sulotion:

```
    exec("start /B $py_bg $python $py_script $py_stdout $py_stderror");
```

But same result. How can I solve this problem?

=== UPDATE:

I used `start /B`  in the wrong way, I changed my code to this:

```
<?PHP
    $python    = 'C:\\Users\\User\\anaconda3\\python.exe';
    $py_script = 'C:\\wamp\\www\\lab\\ex\\simple_test.py';
    $py_stdout    = '> temp\\'.session_id()."_std.txt";
    $py_stderror  = '2> temp\\'.session_id()."_stde.txt";
    $py_cmd = "$python $py_script $py_arg_1 $py_std $py_stde";

    pclose(popen("start /B ". $py_cmd, "a"));
```

But now a Warning in PHP for `popen()`:

> Warning: popen(start /B ...,a): No error in C:\wamp\www\lab\start.php on line 50

and an other for `pclose()`:

> Warning: pclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, bool given in ...

Comment: Not sure if https://stackoverflow.com/a/45721544/1213708 works.

Comment: thanks, I changed my way for use `start /B`, but the problem not solved yet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042591/windows-php-pclose-and-popen-issue

Comment: Error handling for `popen()` is useful, but not solve the main problem here. I'm working around this function and my code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked [PHP: popen - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php)  and see there `a` is not a valid mode, but I see this on several answers around here!

however:

> The mode. Either 'r' for reading, or 'w' for writing.

By changing mode to `r`, the script call and run in the background correctly and there is not an error or warning on PHP or Py.

```
<?PHP
    $python    = 'C:\\Users\\User\\anaconda3\\python.exe';
    $py_script = 'C:\\wamp\\www\\lab\\ex\\simple_test.py';
    $py_stdout    = '> temp\\'.session_id()."_std.txt";
    $py_stderror  = '2> temp\\'.session_id()."_stde.txt";
    $py_cmd = "$python $py_script $py_arg_1 $py_std $py_stde";

    pclose(popen("start /B ". $py_cmd, "r"));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !! You have ended my 200 hours of searching.