# using the DOS start command when passed arguments have quotes

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I have a question about the DOS start command. 
I have already read this topic:
Using the DOS “start” command with parameters passed to the started program
[Using the "start" command with parameters passed to the started program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154075/using-the-dos-start-command-with-parameters-passed-to-the-started-program)

but my question is a little different.

I  have this problem: I need to pass paths that need to be quoted.

For example, if path have no quotes this works fine:

start "" app.exe -option c:\myapp\myfile.txt

but if path have double quotes it doesn't works.

I have this line in my  BATCH file:

start "" myapp.exe -option %mypath%

and when %mypath% contains double quotes (paths that have spaces or other characters in names) the start command returns very strange results.

Thanks
Sandro

Comment: You might should look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562038/escaping-double-quotes-in-batch-script

Answer (score 4):

Normally it's not a problem to use parameters there with quotes, but you get problems if your app-path has also quotes.

Then you need to add an extra `CALL` statement.

```
start "" app.exe -option c:\myapp\myfile.txt    - Works
start "" app.exe -option "c:\myapp\myfile.txt"    - Works
start "" "app.exe" -option c:\myapp\myfile.txt    - Works

start "" "app.exe" -option "c:\myapp\myfile.txt"    - Don't works
start "" CALL "app.exe" -option "c:\myapp\myfile.txt"    - Works
```

Comment: Ahh nice, you're running the "call" command and then passing the program and arguments to that. Note for Googlers: -option is not a part of the generic answer, it's just there because it was in the asker's question.

Comment: **Also note that you could just call cd "path" beforehand.** The start command has a /d option to set the working directory for the command it calls/process it starts.

Comment: Also add CMD /C to prevent a hang of new opened window, if you invoke a `.bat` file - `START "dummy header"  CMD /C  CALL "C:\my apps\my.bat" "param - 1" param_2`

Answer (score 1):

This might help, but it is a **bit way round about** method and slight modification may required to suit your need.

The idea is to:

1. Dump the environment variable which has quotes to a text file with a predefined name. Like:"set mypath2 > withQt.bat"
2. Use windows [power shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034/how-can-you-find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-the-windows-command-line-envir) or some third party tool to find and replace quotes in that file.
3. Create another text file (one time step only) containing string "Set "
4. Use copy command to append the file mentioned in step2 with the file created in step3 and create a batch file with a predefined name. Like: copy base.bat + withQt.bat withtqt.bat
5. Run the batch file, which creates another/replaces the environment variable with value without quotes.

Sorry, I couldn't get something more elegant at this time.