# Word 2010 /m switch from batch file

Tags: macros, batch-file, ms-word, cmd

I'm trying to execute a Word macro from a batch file. The documentation [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210565) indicates that this is accomplished using the /mMacroname switch.

However, when I do this, I receive an "Invalid switch - /mMacroname" error. It seems I'm doing something wrong, but I can't for the life of me figure out what it is.

The name of the macro is FormatStrikethrough. It opens/closes/etc. the file on its own. I am invoking it like so:

```
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\winword.exe" /mFormatStrikethrough
```

Comment: It tells me that /m is invalid, rather than /mFormatStrikethrough

Comment: Does it do what you want if you drop the start command?

Comment: Thank you, sir. Switching to a "cd <pathname>" syntax then executing winword.exe directly fixed it for me. If you submit it as an answer, I'll mark it correct.

Comment: You don't need to switch to the directory first, you can just run `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\winword.exe"` directly. Sorry that I overlooked the `start`.

Comment: I haven't tried it - will the quotes not throw it off?

Comment: Answered my own question - no the quotes will not throw it off. Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dropping the `start` from the command will make it work.

I believe this is because your parameters were being passed to `start` rather than the `winword` executable. As for how to use start to launch a program with switches,

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154075/using-the-dos-start-command-with-parameters-passed-to-the-started-program) seems to tell you how to do that.