# How to automate user input to a executable?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, automation, exe

I have a .exe file which when called from the Windows Command prompt, first connects to a server and then requests for user input as a confirmation.
Something like below:

```
C:\SomePath\AnotherFolder>TheApplication.exe download
Logging in to Vault server myserver.app.cosmos...
Logged in to the Vault server

Downloading will overwrite existing files.
Download scripts for context 'COSMOS' to folder:
 C:\Work\MyFolder\TEST?
(y/n): n  <--- n was my input

Press any key to exit... <--- here i pressed y
```

I want to automate this process.

I tried the below line from the Windows command prompt:

```
 echo n|TheApplication.exe download
```

I even tried :

```
 (echo n && echo y)|TheApplication.exe download  <-- the y for the last user input request to close the app.
```

But in both cases its throwing the below error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot read keys when either application does not have a console or when console input has been redirected from a file. Try Console.Read.
   at System.Console.ReadKey(Boolean intercept)
   at System.Console.ReadKey()
   at TheApplication.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

**disclaimer: TheApplication.exe is a third party executable. I cannot change anything inside it.

PS: If needed I can run this from a powershell console if its not possible from windows command prompt or I can also include the whole thing inside a batch script.

But any how I need to automate this.

Comment: Yep its a .net app. And as far as my knowledge goes it runs on .Net Framework 4.5.2

Comment: You'll have to get the app vendor to help you change `Console.ReadKey()`  to  `Console.Read()`

Comment: Read the documentation for your .EXE. When you're lucky, there are some command line parameters (aka switches) to replace the keyboard input.

Comment: see if your app has some sort of help section built in. `TheApplication.exe /?` or `-h` or `--help` etc. to see if there might be some parameters for defaults maybe, as mentioned by @Stephan

Comment: @GerhardBarnard so no way this can be done using a batch script or powershell or anything else?

Comment: Dis you check if the app has any help yet?

Comment: Yep, No luck there

Comment: You'll have to ask the vendor then unfortunately.

Comment: If you are using CMD, you can use the < operator to read a file as keyboard input. Example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17020106/how-to-make-an-exe-application-read-input-from-batch-file-instead-of-typing-it I can't find a way to do this in powershell though.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use PowerShell...

**autoinput.ps1**

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Start-Sleep -m 1000
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("ny")
```

The command is:

```
powershell .\autoinput.ps1 & .\TheApplication.exe
```

Comment: We just told the OP that it will not except input from `stdin` because of `Console.ReadKey()` So no matter how you redirect it, it will not accept it.

Comment: I made a mistake. I rewrote my answer.