# Ipython Notebook: Open & Edit Files

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am scratching my head on what the standard workflow is for opening, editing and executing a scripts directly from within the ipython notebook? I know that you can use %edit from ipython terminal but this doesn't seem to work from notebook.

thank you

Answer (score 2):

in ipython 1.1.0 I just ran "!gvim a.py" in the notebook which opened the gvim editor in a window. After saving the edits into a.py file, I was able to successfully execute "%run a.py"

Comment: Interesting. When I try to run !vi a.py in the notebook it renders the script inside the notebook in a broken and uneditable format rather than opening the script in my vi editor in the terminal.

Comment: Ah probably you need an editor that brings up a separate window. Notebook does not allow interactive edits.

Comment: !gvim locks the kernel for me until vim closes (using a batch in Windows). Any clue on how run and detach with a bang?

Comment: Can't edit comments? Here is why I needed to start cmd /c ...: http://stackoverflow.com/a/154090/770443