# using a batch file to run a ps1 file but hide the command prompt after start?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I build a small tool with powershell and i open it through a batch-file.
Batch file has the following content :

```
powershell -file "D:\scripts\Powershell\xxx.ps1"
```

Now it opens my tool but always displays the command prompt in background. I want the CMD to be hidden after running my file.

How to achieve that? I tried `-hidden`  but then my programm is hidden :D

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using the [`START`](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) utility in your batch file, it will launch the program in a new window and allow the batch's `cmd` window to exit in the background.

```
START powershell -file "D:\scripts\Powershell\xxx.ps1"
```

Be aware `START` exhibits [potentially] unexpected behavior when the [first parameter contains double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/154075/260545).

If you're using GUI elements, or external applications, and you want to hide Powershell's window, but not the GUI, try the following:

```
START powershell -WindowStyle Hidden "D:\scripts\Powershell\xxx.ps1"
```

---

Here's an example of how I've used batch in tandem with PowerShell GUI:

Contents of C:\call.cmd:

```
START "" powershell -NoLogo -WindowStyle Hidden "C:\gui.ps1"
```

Contents of C:\gui.ps1:

```
# VB Assembly GUI example
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::MsgBox(
    "Do you like VB in PowerShell?",
    [Microsoft.VisualBasic.MsgBoxStyle]::YesNo,
    "Hello"
)

# Windows Forms GUI example
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show(
    "Do you like Windows Forms?",
    "Hello",
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::YesNo
)

# External app GUI example
& notepad.exe
```

Running the `call.cmd` batch will use `START` to launch PowerShell [exiting `cmd`] and PowerShell will hide its window, but otherwise display the GUI elements executed from the PS1 file.

Comment: hey nice to meet you again. Now i have an empty Powershell window opented +  my program. Is there a way to have just my program ?

Comment: Does the `xxx.ps1` script launch an external application, or create is's own GUI?  Just trying to understand what exactly you require.

Comment: I've added an example adapted from some stuff I've used before. It should allow you to display GUI elements from a PS1, but hide the PowerShell window.