# Starting and ending batch files

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am attempting to start recording the screen using Camtasia however am triggering this using a batch file.

As i need the recordings to be 30 seconds long, i have a secondary batch file. It doesn't work as intended as i would like to avoid multiple windows executing the commands opening. I know the command `taskkill` isn't correct and have included it to illustrate what i am intending to achieve.

The batch files need to be able to run on both Windows 7 and Windows 8 devices.

The process is started with a starting batch file that launches the secondary batch file to commence the countdown.

**StartFile.bat**

```
start EndFile.bat
"C:\Program Files\TechSmith\Camtasia Studio 8\CamRecorder.exe" /record
```

**EndFile.bat**

```
timeout /T 30 /NOBREAK
"C:\Program Files\TechSmith\Camtasia Studio 8\CamRecorder.exe" /stop
timeout /T 30 /NOBREAK
taskkill /f /im StartFile.bat <-- To kill the first batch file so there aren't multiple windows
start StartFile.bat <-- To create a new instance of the starting batch file.
exit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do it all in a single batch file with a `GOTO` loop (edited to take account of the discussion in the comments; the `start` is only needed because starting recording doesn't return control):

```
:startofloop
start "" "C:\Program Files\TechSmith\Camtasia Studio 8\CamRecorder.exe" /record
timeout /T 30 /NOBREAK
"C:\Program Files\TechSmith\Camtasia Studio 8\CamRecorder.exe" /stop
timeout /T 30 /NOBREAK
goto startofloop
```

Comment: That won't work as `"C:\Program Files\TechSmith\Camtasia Studio 8\CamRecorder.exe" /record
timeout /T 30 /NOBREAK` doesn't kick in as the recording is perpetual until the command `"C:\Program Files\TechSmith\Camtasia Studio 8\CamRecorder.exe" /stop` is called.

Comment: You mean that calling `CamRecorder.exe` ties up the command prompt until the process is stopped instead of opening the recorder and returning straight away?

Comment: Does it work if you do `start "C:\Program Files\TechSmith\Camtasia Studio 8\CamRecorder.exe" /record` as the second line instead?

Comment: Does it work if you begin the second line of my version of the batch file with the word `start`?

Comment: No it doesn't. The error i get is that /record is an invalid switch

Comment: Try adding some an empty `""` as well after the `start`, as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154075/using-the-dos-start-command-with-parameters-passed-to-the-started-program