# How set affinity running java from console

Tags: java, windows, jar, console, affinity

Since I dont have hyper threading option in the BIOS I am gonna disable it by launching

start /affinity 01010101

like [here](https://superuser.com/questions/305887/disable-hyperthreading-in-the-windows-7-registry)

The problem is that I would like to run a java program with that option but I cant make it

```
C:\Users\gbarbieri>start /affinity 01010101 "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\j
re\bin\java.exe" -jar D:\Documents\NetBeansProjects\EC_400_BETA\dist\EC_400_BETA
.jar
Die Datei "-jar" kann nicht gefunden werden.(= -jar cannot be found)
```

I tried include -jar in the `''`, include also the .jar, but nothing..

So how do I set affinity running a jar from console?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using the DOS "start" command with parameters passed to the started program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154075/using-the-dos-start-command-with-parameters-passed-to-the-started-program)

Comment: I think the question I linked above in the duplicate comment explains for you what the problem is and how to solve it (using double quotes with the windows `start` command has a special meaning, so you should first have empty double quotes if you need to use double quotes in the command name)

Comment: It seems working, if u wanna answer I will accept it, @ErwinBolwidt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be marked as a duplicate of [Using the "start" command with parameters passed to the started program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154075/using-the-dos-start-command-with-parameters-passed-to-the-started-program) . However, I only found out that there was a another question with the right solution after finding out why the OP's command line didn't work.

The problem is that the Windows `start` command treats the first argument in double quotes specially. It treats it as the title to display in the command prompt window. (See the [Microsoft documentation](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/start.mspx?mfr=true))

The work around is to provide a title explicitly before providing a command name that needs double quotes (such as any command inside `c:\Program Files\` because of the space in that path name)

This could just be an empty title, like this:

```
C:\Users\gbarbieri>start "" /affinity 01010101 "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\j
re\bin\java.exe" -jar D:\Documents\NetBeansProjects\EC_400_BETA\dist\EC_400_BETA
.jar
```

Comment: @elect It looks like the start command doesn't care where you put the first double-quoted argument (before, after or in between options)