# Detect commandline application from CMD without messing with PATH variable or System32/SysWow64 dir

Tags: windows, windows-8, cmd, registry, windows-shell

### Scenario

I would like to install an *x86* CommandLine application on a folder outside `C:\Windows\System32` or `C:\Windows\Syswow64` and still be able to access my app under CMD without adding my application's path inside the `PATH` environment variable.

### Question

Is this possible to do? Maybe touching a needed registry keys?

Note: I know how to add my application into `PATH` variable/regvalue or how to access my application from CMD putting the required .exe in the `System32`/`SysWow64` folder. This question is only to learn alternatives, it's not to solve issues with `PATH` or **System** dirs.

### Code

I've tried this suggested approach from a comment of @Sertac Akyuz in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27109611/expand-an-x86-exe-to-c-windows-system32-under-both-windows-x86-and-x64), I have stored `MyApp.exe` on `C:\` root directory, but I can't detect the application just putting `MyApp.exe` under the CMD.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\MyApp.exe]
@="C:\\MyApp.exe"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\MyApp.exe]
@="C:\\MyApp.exe"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\MyApp.exe]
@="C:\\MyApp.exe"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\MyApp.exe]
@="C:\\MyApp.exe"
```

Comment: App Paths does not apply for command prompt. But you can cheat with App Paths registry. You can create an entry for `cmd.exe` itself and create there the `Path` key value with the path to your app. Path from this key value is then appended to the environment variable of the application (in this case the command prompt).

Comment: FYI: App Paths is not used by cmd.exe but is used by other shells, for example tcc.exe: http://jpsoft.com/tccle-cmd-replacement.html

Comment: If you want to run from command line an application that has been included in `App Paths`, you need to use `start MyApp`.

Comment: I'm finding the question a bit odd, as I don't understand what exact problem you are wanting to solve. You just want the command to be runnable from any CMD prompt, but without altering PATH ? There's plenty of methods. First one : provide the full path of the exectuable. If you don't want to change PATH, what else do you expect ? Maybe check if you can use aliassing (similar to Linux/Unix). Or shortcuts, scripts, ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`App Paths` registry settings - used by Windows Explorer, to locate programs when you type program name in "Run..." box, and so on. These settings are not affecting `cmd.exe` behavior.

The only way to set up `cmd.exe` paths for searching applications *is* changing `PATH` environment variable. You can start `cmd.exe` from your own `.bat`/`.cmd` where you set up all required variables for current session, without changing it globally.