# Force install file in c:\windows\system32 on x64 and x86

Tags: inno-setup

I have an Inno Setup script, which need to force copy a dll to c:\windows\system32 even if the system x64.

My script this is.

```
...[Setup]
AppId={{7D59F7E8-DDCD-4DD2-9AC1-47F95E819F50}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName=c:\{#MyAppName}
DisableDirPage=yes
DefaultGroupName={#MyAppName}
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
OutputDir=Y:\Dropbox\ADM - Atomicti\AtomicSync64\AtomicSync
OutputBaseFilename=AtomicSync_Setup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
AlwaysRestart=yes

[Files]
Source: "Y:\Dropbox\ADM - Atomicti\AtomicSync64\AtomicSync.dll"; DestDir: "{sys}"; Flags: 32bit 
Source: "Y:\Dropbox\ADM - Atomicti\AtomicSync64\AtomicSync.dll"; DestDir: "c:\AtomicSync"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "Y:\Dropbox\ADM - Atomicti\AtomicSync64\AtomicSync\AtomicSync.conf"; DestDir: "c:\AtomicSync"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "Y:\Dropbox\ADM - Atomicti\AtomicSync64\AtomicSync\AtomicSync.log"; DestDir: "c:\AtomicSync"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "Y:\Dropbox\ADM - Atomicti\AtomicSync64\AtomicSync\AtomicSync64 - Reset.reg"; DestDir: "c:\AtomicSync"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "Y:\Dropbox\ADM - Atomicti\AtomicSync64\AtomicSync\AtomicSync64.reg"; DestDir: "c:\AtomicSync"; Flags: ignoreversion
...
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Expand an x86 .exe to 'C:\Windows\System32' under both Windows x86 and x64?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27109611/expand-an-x86-exe-to-c-windows-system32-under-both-windows-x86-and-x64)

Comment: Good, thanks. Resolved the problens.