# How to obtain the filename in windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file

The program ImageMagick has a `convert` command which can be used to convert the picture format. For example I have a picture `test.jpg`

```
convert test.jpg test.png
```

will give the test.png.

I want to add this command to the right-click menu to simplify my work. I add a item into the `regedit` at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT -- * -- shell`

```
C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.3-Q16\convert.exe -density 600 "%1" %1.png
```

When I run this command to file `test.jpg`, it will give `test.jpg.png`. I want to get the file `test.png`. How should I modify the command line?

Comment: Change the final `%1.png` to `"%~dpn1.png"`, or possibly `"%~n1.png"` depending upon your input variable.

Comment: You could have just put a batch file in your sendto folder.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the shell handlers support this directly, but I would work it around with `cmd` that has the features needed:

```
cmd /d /c "for /f "delims=" %%i in ('@echo %1') do @start "" "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.3-Q16\convert.exe" -density 600 "%1" "%%~dpni.png""
```

- `@echo %1` echoes the shell-supplied full path which makes it available for CMD as a processable result. The expression is in single quotes because that is what makes it a command.
- `for /f` parses that result as a list of strings (containing one string), puts each (one) string into `%i` and allows the `%~dpni` that [takes drive letter, path and name](https://superuser.com/q/489240/52365) (but not extension) out of the `%i`.
- `@start` is used to not make the CMD wait for the program to finish. Empty quotes after `start` are [very required](https://stackoverflow.com/a/154090/11683).

Answer (score 0):

Your method is good. While You need to change the syntax a little from:

```
C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.3-Q16\convert.exe -density 600 "%1" %1.png
```

to

```
C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.3-Q16\convert.exe -density 600 "%1" "%~n1.png"
```

I Hope this will work out your problems. But, If Not - You can make a Batch file containing this command (2nd one, which is modified by me) and Save it somewhere in PC (Say **"C:\MyScript.Bat"**)

And, Try making the key in registry as:

```
C:\MyScript.bat "%1"
```

And, THat's the flexible way of doing it. **Note:** The code in batch will be as:

```
"C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.3-Q16\convert.exe" -density 600 "%1" "%~n1.png"
```

Any changes you wanna make in right click context menu, You can apply with the changing the **Batch file**.

Hope I Helped!

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The first approach doesn't work and give `%~n1.png`. I tried the second approach and it doesn't work. Maybe I did some operation wrong. Can you have you try?

Comment: There is already a [deleted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42608388/11683) that suggests using `%~n1.png`. It does not work. The batch file should work.