# Execute Windows run dialog command in command prompt

Tags: windows, command-prompt, special-folders

In the Windows Run dialog, I can use the command `shell:startup` to open the user's startup folder.

In hope to be able to use the command in the Windows command line, I tried typing `shell` in the command prompt, but returned with the error message

```
'shell' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How can I execute such run line commands in the command prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The run dialog accepts not only a command but also a URL/URI or **any real paths,** as you can see from its description:

[image: Run dialog]

That's why when you open `shell:startup` which is a special path (specified in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\explorer\FolderDescriptions`) it works normally

However in Windows cmd or PowerShell the command must be an executable file, a script file or any other files with a *registered* type. It won't accept a folder. To work around that use either of the following

```bat
start shell:startup
explorer shell:startup
```

If the path contains spaces then in cmd you must [add another empty parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/154090/995714) due to the legacy issues in cmd.exe

```bat
start "" "shell:common startup"
```

If you use PowerShell then `start "shell:common startup"` will work normally because `start` is an alias to [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.1) in PowerShell. If you run `explorer` then you don't need that empty string either

Comment: Thanks! How do I echo the shell:startup.

Comment: what do you mean by echo shell:startup? Why do you want to print that out?

Comment: Yes. I want to print the end folder. Something like echo %shell:startup%

Comment: @Andoo that's outside of the scope of this question and is trickier. Please open another question to ask this

Answer (score 0):

Use the start-command, like the following:

```
start shell:startup
```

You can also use *start /?* to display help of the start-command.