# Getting windows to start R in batch mode using the Start command

Tags: windows, r, batch-file, command-prompt

I know I must be making a simple syntax mistake, but I want to have a windows batch file that fires up 9 instances of R and runs a different routine in each one. I want these to run simultaneously (i.e. asynchronously). I can fire up 9 command prompt windows and type a command in each one, but it seems like with the START command I should be able to make them start from a single batch file.

Here's an example of how I start one of the instances of R:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\R\R-2.8.1\bin\R" CMD BATCH "C:\Users\jd\Documents\mexico\Estado\getdata1.r"
```

Reading this [previous stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72671/how-to-create-batch-file-in-windows-using-start-with-a-path-and-command-with-sp) along with [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154075/using-the-dos-start-command-with-parameters-passed-to-the-started-program) makes me think I should be able to do this:

```
START "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\R\R-2.8.1\bin\R" CMD BATCH "C:\Users\jd\Documents\mexico\Estado\getdata1.r" /b
```

That does not return an error, it just returns a prompt and R never starts. What am I missing?

Comment: Is "/b" a parameter for the START command? I think it gets passed to the R program. Try changing it to START /b .... but I'm not sure that this really explains the problem (R never starts).

Comment: @Roman, I ended up building Segue :) If I were to try and solve that same problem today I would use Multicore or doRedis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer.  On windows when running command use "Rcmd" not "R CMD".  There is a separate exe for running the commands.  Look in the bin folder of your R installation.

Comment: but snow is certainly the more sophisticated way to parallelize a job.

Comment: yes, snow is more sophisticated... and with that sophistication comes a lot of overhead

Answer (score 5):

I would do two things differently:

1. Use R itself to dispatch nine different jobs; the [snow](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/snow/) package is very good at this even when do not use MPI / PVM / NWS for distributed work. Some examples for snow use are for example in my 'introduction to high performance computing with R' tutorials linked from [this page](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/presentations.html).  With snow, you get 'parallel' versions of the apply functions that you can run over multiple instances of R running on the local computer (or of course a network of computers if have one).  The r-sig-hpc list is helpful for more detailed questions.
2. Switch to using Rscript.exe instead of using 'R CMD BATCH'.  On Linux / OS X you also get a choice of using littler

That said, I run almost all my jobs on Linux so there may be a Windows-specific answer here too that I just do not know.  But the above is generic and stays in the platform-agnostic spirit of R.

Comment: OK that makes really good sense. I need to break down and spend a day wrapping my feeble brain around snow and MPI. Parallel process is certainly the future, but I've been slow to get ramped up.

Comment: And the nice thing is that you do can experiment with snow using just network sockets on the local machine before jumping to MPI.

That said, nine jobs on a single machine may exhaust your memory anyway.

Answer (score 2):

It was not immediately clear from the other answers how to actually make this work (without resorting to parallel processing alternatives, so here is a solution I found that works very simply on windows

If you have a simple r file:

```
for(i in 1:10){
  ptm0 <- proc.time()
  Sys.sleep(0.5)  
  ptm1=proc.time() - ptm0
  jnk=as.numeric(ptm1[3])
  cat('\n','It took ', jnk, "seconds to do iteration", i)
}
```

On CMD, specify the directory of where your script is and then start a new window with Rscript to run your code. Multiple lines will open multiple r instances that run your code that also reproduce the messages that the code outputs.

```
cd "C:\rcode"
START "" Rscript example_code.r /b
START "" Rscript example_code.r /b
```

If Rscript is not on the system path, just specify the full path instead:

```
START "" "C:\Program Files\R\bin\x64\Rscript.exe" text_within_loop.r /b
```