# Windows batch R Sweave error loading packages

Tags: windows, r, batch-file, sweave

I am having trouble finding clear documentation on how to set up a batch file for a Sweave document on Windows XP.

I am using the batch  files that are found [here](http://cran.r-project.org/contrib/extra/batchfiles/)

I have created a batch file names `run.bat` which contains the following:

```
Sweave myFile.Rnw
```

The first thing I do in my Sweave file after setting the wd is read in a dataset using the `RODBC` package:

```
library(RODBC)
fetch <- odbcConnect("myDatabase")
myData <- "select * from myTable"
x <- sqlQuery(fetch, myData)
odbcCloseAll()
```

When I run my batch file, I receive the following error:

```
Error: chunk 2
Error in library(RODBC) : there is no package called RODBC
In addition: Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE, :
    there is no package called 'xtable'
```

Obviously these packages do exist and are functional, but something isn't right in the permissions or it isn't finding the right directories. Any thoughts?

Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188544/getting-windows-to-start-r-in-batch-mode-using-the-start-command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an immediate solution to my problem, though understand there are certain limitations to this method. I abandoned using the CRAN provided .bat files for dynamically finding the appropriate path to R and hardcoded the path to R as such:

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-2.11.0\bin\Rterm.exe" --vanilla <%run.r>%run.r
 del *.log
 del *.aux
```

This `.bat` file will fire up R, run the script `run.r` which contains two commands:

```
Sweave("myFile.Rnw")
tools::texi2dvi("myFile.tex", pdf=TRUE)
```

and then cleans up the intermediate `.log` and `.aux` files from the LaTeX output. Obviously, the bulk of the work is done in `myFile.Rnw` but this will atleast let me click one button, perform my analysis, and generate the PDF file.

If someone can think of a way to make this more efficient, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

What does this return when you type it in R (in the GUI) ?

```
 .libPaths()
```

What does it show when you run in the Rnw file?

The documentation in `help(Startup)` will have several suggestions as to where you can set R_LIBS and its variants.

Comment: `.libPaths()` returns `"C:/Program Files/R/R-2.11.0/library"` when running from the GUI using Eclipse. When running directly from the R GUI console, it returns `"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-211~1.0/library"`. Checking out the help page for `Startup` now...

Comment: That would be the same, albeit printed differently.  Do you actually have the RODBC package installed ?

Comment: Well, yes and no. `RODBC` is installed in the version of R that I use with eclipse or directly with the R GUI. I am able to run the script with no trouble from either of these. However, I noticed that the DOS prompt was referring to a Revolution Enterprise iteration of R that I had installed. I uninstalled Revolution Enterprise since I don't use it, and now am receiving the error `Error: R not found`. I have modified the default directory for R so I can save separate instances of R ('R\R-2.11` and `R\R-2.10`..). I need to modify the Sweave.bat file to find my R directory...will look into now

Comment: Adjust your environment variables like PATH accordingly and you should be fine.  This is *your local admin problem* so you need to fix it.

Comment: @Chase I got the same `R not found` error after Windows update, even though I presumably have the correct `PATH` pointing to R - aaargh! My mother warned me not to do updates.

Comment: That's why I always install into something like `C:/opt/R/Rcurrent`, ie I do _not_ accept the default of `R-$Version`.  And the $PATH stays the same....