# How to make a bat file run two jars in parallel?

Tags: windows, batch-file, window, parallels

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I run a bat file in the background from another bat file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649634/how-do-i-run-a-bat-file-in-the-background-from-another-bat-file)

I want to make a bat file that run a local server (Seleneium grid2 *.jar) and then excute command to assign nodes to it. My problem is that when I call this

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0.jar -role hub
call assign-node.bat
```

The bat file runs the server and keeps listening without running the second command  (call)!

What is the best way to do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use two separate batch files. Or

```
start java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0.jar -role hub
call assign-node.bat
```

the *start* command should run it in background mode. didn't tested it.

check:

[How to create batch file in Windows using "start" with a path and command with spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72671/how-to-create-batch-file-in-windows-using-start-with-a-path-and-command-with-s)