# Why does windows START command not work with spaces in arguments AND path?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line-arguments

This command works

```
START /b /wait "Dummy title" "C:\tmp\test runner2.bat" arg1 arg2
```

But both of these fails!

```
START /b /wait "Dummy title" "C:\tmp\test runner2.bat" arg1 arg2 "arg 3" arg4
START /b /wait "Dummy title" "C:\tmp\test runner2.bat" arg1 arg2 "arg 3"
```

The error is:

```
'C:\tmp\test' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Obviously it has something to do with `"` surounding the arguments, but why and how do I work around this?

Related questions:

- [How to create batch file in Windows using “start” with a path and command with spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72671/how-to-create-batch-file-in-windows-using-start-with-a-path-and-command-with-s)
- [Can I use the “start” command with spaces in the path?](https://superuser.com/questions/239565/can-i-use-the-start-command-with-spaces-in-the-path)

Comment: Does it work without start? `"C:\tmp\test runner2.bat" arg1 arg2 "arg 3" arg4`

Comment: Yes it does, I will probably use that as a workaround but it does not answer my question. Thanks though.

Comment: Use `call`, not `start`, for running batch scripts from other batch scripts.

Comment: @devnull That won't return to the calling script.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I was simply trying to figure whether the command works *as is* or not.  If it didn't work as is, chances are that it wouldn't work with `start` or `call` or whatever.

Comment: @devnull It does work with `call`.

Comment: What if the command is not a batch script (but an .exe file)? Then `CALL` wont work, right? I haven't tested it but I would assume that the  original question would remain even if that would be the case?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's a *known* bug of the START command.
If you have spaces in both, the command and of the parameters and try to handle them with quotes, it fails.

First the START command check if the full command exists.
But then it starts only the first part.

In your case it looks for `"C:\tmp\test runner2.bat"` but try to start `C:\tmp\test`.

You can avoid it when the command is replaced by a `CALL`

```
START /b /wait "Dummy title" CALL "C:\tmp\test runner2.bat" arg1 arg2 "arg 3" arg4
```

The `START` uses `cmd /k` to start the new process.
And that is the cause for the misbehaviour.
Paul Groke mentioned the fact, that this only occours when it's a batch file.
`Exe` files will be executed directly and so they are not affected by the cmd.exe bug.

In your case

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe  /K "C:\tmp\test runner2.bat" arg1 arg2 "arg 3" arg4
```

And the help of `cmd /k` and `cmd /c` explains, that in this case the first and last quote are removed.

Comment: I tried it about one hour ... but against a bug of course I can do nothing :)

Comment: This only seems to happen if `start` is used to execute a batch file. If start is used to start a `.exe`, this problem does *not* occur.

Comment: 4 years later and this is still a bug... But so thanks for a very usefull answer :)

Answer (score 10):

"Jeb" already pointed into the right direction. In my case i didn't tried to run a batch, but a program in the "Program Files" folder (batch shall terminate after launching the program). When calling

```
START "C:\Program Files\MyAppPath\MyApp.exe" arg1 arg2 ... argN
```

the path typed with quotes around is supposed to be the "Title" parameter by START command. To get rid of that, you have to "fake" a window title like that:

```
START "" "C:\Program Files\MyAppPath\MyApp.exe" arg1 arg2 ... argN
```

This helped in my case.

Comment: Sorry - I have overseen that the problem belongs to spaces in both PATH and ARGUMENTS...

Comment: That helped mine as well :D

Comment: For God's sake... I lost some time with this. It should be "start" then what I want to start.

Answer (score 3):

This does not answer my question, but it does solve the immediate problem I'm having.

While reading through the "[Problem with quotes around file names in Windows command shell](https://superuser.com/questions/238810/problem-with-quotes-around-file-names-in-windows-command-shell)"-post I discovered a workaround:

```
cmd.exe /C ""C:\tmp\test runner2.bat" arg1 arg2 "arg 3" arg4"
```

There is also the other workaround by simply executing the command with the `call` command instead (as stated by [Ansgar Wiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674255/why-does-windows-start-command-not-work-with-spaces-in-arguments-and-path?noredirect=1#comment25746830_17674255))

```
call "C:\tmp\test runner2.bat" arg1 arg2 "arg 3" arg4
```