# Open a file with spaces in the filename when a filename is a parameter

Tags: cmd

I need to open a file which contain spaces in the filename.

```
FILE1="Some text with spaces.txt"
cmd /c start ${FILE1}
```

The only solution I found is using `if` loop, but it is not what I need

```
for file1 in *.txt
```

Solution with quotes doesn't work:

```
cmd /c start "${FILE1}"
cmd /c start `${FILE1}`
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is that bash (Unix) or cmd (Windows) ?

Comment: @philant cmd(Windows)

Comment: this appears to be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72671/how-to-create-batch-file-in-windows-using-start-with-a-path-and-command-with-s