# How to launch an exe file from a Batch file within an other batch file from different directories?

Tags: windows, batch-file, call

I will try to explain my problem :

- I have a main batch file, named master.bat
- I have several batch files, named slave_0x.bat called from master.bat with the CALL command.
- Each slave_0x.bat file launch a setup_0x.exe file from a relative directory.
- These two files are located in a sub-directory from the master.bat directory.

Per example :

- master.bat file is located in D:\Master\
- slave_01.bat is located in D:\Master\Slave_01\
- setup_01.exe is also located in D:\Master\Slave_01\

The problem is :

When I launch master.bat, the current path is "D:\Master\"
Then, when slave_01.bat is executed, it try to launch setup_01.exe from "D:\Master\" and not from "D:\Master\Slave\"

```
REM Master.bat

@ECHO OFF
TITLE Installing Applications

SET mypath=%~dp0
ECHO %mypath:~0,-1%

ECHO.
ECHO 1) Installing App 1
ECHO.

call D:\Master\Slave_01\slave_01.bat"

ECHO.
ECHO 2) Installing App 2
ECHO.

CALL D:\Master\Slave_02\slave_02.bat"

PAUSE
```

slave_0x files :

```
REM slave_01.bat

TITLE App 1

ECHO.
ECHO %mypath:~0,-1%
ECHO.

ECHO Installing App 1
ECHO Please wait...

START /wait setup_01.exe /SILENT /SP- /NORESTART
```

Is there a way to use the current directory from the slave_0x.bat file instead the current directory from the master.bat file in the slave_0x.bat to launch the setup_0x.exe file from the right directory ?

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To launch an executable that is in a different directory, add the relative path to the `START` command.  Use `%~dp0` to get the path of the currently running batch file.

```
START /wait %~dp0\setup_01.exe /SILENT /SP- /NORESTART
```

This launches the executable, but it doesn't change the process current directory.

If your executable relies on the current directory, then you will need to `cd` to that directory first.  The easiest way to temporarily change directories is `pushd` and `popd`.

```
pushd %~dp0
START /wait setup_01.exe /SILENT /SP- /NORESTART
popd
```

**Note**: If the path or executable name can contain spaces, put the executable name in quotes as follows (including the mandatory dummy quotes)

```
START /wait "" "%~dp0\setup_01.exe" /SILENT /SP- /NORESTART
```

This is a common gotcha using the batch `START` command.  See [How to create batch file in Windows using "start" with a path and command with spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72671)