# How can I open an explorer window from a batch script that contains both an environment variable and a space?

Tags: batch-file, environment-variables, windows-explorer

This works:

```
start %appdata%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\
```

These do not:

- `start %localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\`
- `start "%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\"`
- `start %localappdata%\"Google\Chrome\User Data\"`
- `start %localappdata%"\Google\Chrome\User Data\"`

How can I open a Windows Explorer window using a path that has an environment variable and a space?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create batch file in Windows using "start" with a path and command with spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72671/how-to-create-batch-file-in-windows-using-start-with-a-path-and-command-with-s)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem with `start` is that the first quoted argument is handled as a window title. Try with

```
start "" "%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\"
```

Or use

```
explorer /e, "%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
start "Windowtitlewhichcanbebemptyifdesiredbutnotomitted" "%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\"
```