# Executing .exe using CMD Start with Parameter

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have created a executable file lets say 'Startbackup.exe' and it is located in 'D:\Start Backup\Startbackup.exe'

What i am trying to acheive is to create a bactch file to start this .Exe uisng defualt paramter . My parameter is 'Startbackup/run'.

I tried following command in cmd and it works.

[image]

How can i create a .bat file? I have tried following but its not working

```
Start /D D:\Start Backup\ Startbackup Parameter Startbackup/run
```

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72671/how-to-create-batch-file-in-windows-using-start-with-a-path-and-command-with-s

Comment: @RuudHelderman thanks for the link it helps

Comment: Your 'starting directory path' has spaces so should be doublequoted, `Start /D "D:\Start Backup"`. If `startbackup/run` works then it appears that `/run` is your parameter, so all you need is to append that, with an optional/empty title, e.g `Start /D "D:\Start Backup" startbackup /run` or `Start /D "D:\Start Backup" "" startbackup /run`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working now.

```
start "" "D:\Start Backup\StartBackup.exe" parameter StartBackup/Start
```

I dont have any space in my arguments so this solution works.

Answer (score 1):

That is because the first parameter of start is the name, and the second one is the path to the executable.

Try this:

```
Start "" "D:\Start Backup\StartBackup.exe"
```